# Regarding relative velocity of fluid and object in CFD

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

If I want to simulate flow over cynlinder, the common practice is to have the fluid moving at a certain speed and the cylinder stays stationary. I was curious to see what will happen if instead the front of the cylinder is a vector velocity field inlet and the back of the cylinder is a vector velocity field outlet, both are pointing in the direction of negative x; the cylinder is in a very large fluid domain with the domain boundaries set as walls.

I am not looking for Von Karman vortex street, so I simulate it in steady state.I was using COMSOL.

I think the result should be identical with the normal one but it's not.

The velocity magnitude contour looks different . Why is that? Did I do something wrong?

[image: The cylinder is stationary]

[image]

Comment: With a velocity inlet do you mean that you set the velocity of the front of the cylinder to some specific value? For most systems you should apply the no-slip condition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-slip_condition . The no slip condition means that the velocity is zero at the boundary of an object. There is also the stronger condition that the normal component of the velocity should be zero at the boundary. The second condition can't be violated because that would mean fluid is passing through your object. The streamlines of your second plot appear to violate this condition.

Comment: Sorry, I have update the second picture. The streamlines in the orignal one are wrong.

Comment: That looks better but what do you mean with the front is a velocity inlet? could you specify a bit more what you did?

Comment: The front of the cylinder (the left half part of the circle) has a boundary condition and, on that boundary, I can specify the velocity component. Nomally, for the velocity inlet BC, we specify the speed of the flow that is going perpendicular the the boundary, but in this case, I specify the velocity on the boundary to be parallel and pointing to the negative x direction.